# How can I add exception inside my code?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, exception

I want to check if user enters wrong login information inside my winForm...so where can I add exception inside my connection Class?

```
class Connection
    {
        public static OracleConnection Connection(string Source, string Name, string pass)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = null;
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Source) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass))
                {
                    conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + Source + ";User Id=" + Name + ";Password=" + pass + ";");
                    return con;
                }

            return con;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you check if user has entered invalid login info ?

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be used for control flow. SQL will throw an exception for you anyway.

Comment: Do you need to catch an exception or throw one?

Comment: throw one if user login information is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a [Try-Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) around your `conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + Source + ";User Id=" + Name + ";Password=" + pass + ";");` line.  If you get an error, handle it in the Catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `try - catch` block to your `Connection()` method as follows. When user supply invalid user name or password [ORA-1017](http://ora-01017.ora-code.com/) exception will be thrown.

```
class Connection
{
    public static OracleConnection Connection(string Source, string Name, string pass)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = null;

        try         
        {
          if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Source) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass))
             {
                conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + Source + ";User Id=" + Name + ";Password=" + pass + ";");                  
             }              
          return con;
        }
        Catch(Exception exception)
        {
            //ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
        }           
    }
}
```